# Como acceder a un js externo en angular

Tags: javascript, angular12

Posiblemente alguien se ha encontrado en este escenario, necesito acceder a 1 enlace js externo, ejemplo: tengo este recurso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero acceder a ese js desde la misma url y no descargando el file *.js y configurlo en el *.json de angular

Comment: Has probado a añadirlo al fichero HTML? en la base del proyecto debes tener un index.html.

Comment: Eso si funciona gracias por tu respuesta, pero ahora estoy intentando lanzar un dialog con un jQuery externo, algo como esto pero no fucnciona.                                                                             $("#dialog").dialog(
          {
              bgiframe: true,
              autoOpen: false,
              height: 100,
              modal: true
          }
  ); ya instale el modulo y la referencia en angular.json pero nada...

Comment: Sin ver el código y lo que estás intentando no sabría decirte, pero es altamente recomendable NO usar jQuery junto con Angular, todo se complica enormemente.

Comment: Si es lo que me esta pasando jajajaj, intento integrar un componente y la forma en la que esta implementado solicita recibir el resultado en una ventana vía jquery y no he podido lanzarl el dialog desde angular igual gracias por la atención